Unable to open the model Index -1 out of bonds for length 0 . What should i do?
Index -1 out of bonds
The last thing I did before I closed the file is making 3d object and on the next day when I opened it again this image popped up. What should I do to fix this file and what can I do to prevent this from happening again?
I haven't tried anything since I am new to Anylogic and not familiar with the java or anything. Please help me.

Very unusual to see this upon opening a model, tbh. Probably corrupted file. Always keep file backups, ideally with Git versioning or similar... You may need to revert to an older version

I have already done that but I still can't open it. I learned a lot from this so next time I'll prepare backups. Thank you for answering and thank you for the tutorials you make on Youtube! It helped me a lot.
